# Android - save file to Device's "data" folder

Tags: android, file

I need to save some files in the device's "data" folder, because some other application needs them.

I've tried

```
new File("/data/filename").createNewFile();
```

but I get

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Is the path I'm using wrong?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627353/how-to-create-file-directories-and-folders-in-android-data-data-project-filesyst

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does the file get saved using "File file = new file(filename)" in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754141/where-does-the-file-get-saved-using-file-file-new-filefilename-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File directory = cw.getDir("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("/data/filename");

file.mkdirs();

File mFile = new File(file, filename);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the data folder in root?
Then the device must be rooted and you need root permission.